# iOS, openURL opens odd webpage... (welcome to appe.com)

Tags: objective-c, ios, app-store

When user click the link,
it should go to the app store page(angry bird page). 
this is the code:

```
NSString *url = @"http://itunes.apple.com/us/album/angry-birds-rio-samba-single/id426982849?uo=4";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

but, first time when I click the link, it goes to odd webpage. 
(blank white page with text "welcome to appe.com", not apple.com).
and when when I click the link again, it goes to the right page.

anyone who experience with this situation?

this is error page on app store.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's strange. Ia haven't experienced such situation yet. However, the link you are trying to open is not the Angry birds Rio GAME, but a SONG. If you want to lead user to Angry birds Rio game in app store, you should rather use:

```
NSString* urlString=@"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/pl/app/angry-birds-rio/id420635506?mt=8";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
```

(the protocol is not `http://` but `itms-apps://`

Comment: thanks, but I think it's not url problem... anyway, I'll check that.

Answer (score 1):

use this link instead

```
NSString *url = @"http://itunes.apple.com/us/album/angry-birds-rio-samba-single/id426982849?ign-mpt=uo%3D4";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I double-checked the url. and that was the problem.

I use this url,

```
http://itunes.apple.com/us/album/angry-birds-rio-samba-single/id426982849
```

not this correct one,

```
http://itunes.apple.com/us/album/angry-birds-rio-samba-single/id426982849?uo=4
```

I modified the url and it fixed the problem.